# Purposes of SWTOOLS and swshare folders under C:?

Tags: windows-7

My OS is Windows 7. Under C: there are two folders `SWTOOLS` and `swshare`. Does anyone happen to know what they are for and if they are safe to delete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These folders contain drivers, I wouldn't suggest to remove them as [they seem needed for recovery](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht082396).

Comment: Not true on newer machines, but sound advice - I forgot you used to need this stuff for reinstall on the older units!

Answer (score 2):

If you machine is a Lenovo/IBM, these have drivers and software backups.  You PROBABLY CAN delete them, in the sense that the machine will continue to work, but I wouldn't recommend it.